# NSURLRequest receives data too late

Tags: iphone, http, servlets, nsurlrequest

I'm using a NSURLRequest to receive data from an Java Servlet.
The Servlet is writing something to the outputstream immediately.

NSURLRequest immediately receives the response `connection:didReceiveResponse:`, but receiving the data lasts 15 - 20 seconds. (So that's the time between `didReceiveResponse` and `didReceiveData`). It looks like NSURLRequest is buffering the data and waits for more data.

How can I prevent the problem?

Comment: Do you Mean the time between [didReceiveResponse] and [didReceiveData] delegates is taking too long?

Comment: that is definitely a Java Servlet issue, what is the expected size of the outputstream that is going to be written on the stream?

Comment: you should check size of incoming data..as i am also using NSURLRequest and there is no problem at all

Comment: use [response expectedContentLength]; in didReceiveResponse delegate.

Comment: [response expectedContentLength] returns -1. But the data, which has to be received is about 4KB.

Comment: You're having something wrong in the Servlet or you would not have -1 expected size, share the serverlet code if you would like us to have a closer look to the problem.

Comment: You are right. It was an error in the servlet implementation. The Outputstream was not closed after sending the data, but later. Thank you for your help =)

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection use low level buffering to collect the bytes.

There is a difference between didReceiveResponse and didRecieveData - as there would be some proxying/data routing that might cause the delay.

In order to perform your metrics you should be recording the time between first didRecieveData and connectionDidFinishLoading and compare the time when you do same on your web-browser.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I have tested it in the web browser. It also has a delay of 10 - 15 seconds. I think, the servlet doesn't close the stream correctly. I have also an java implementation. There I don't have such a delay.

Comment: Good. Now you are sure that the delay in not due to some inconsistencies in NSURLConnectionDelegates as you can replicate the behaviour in browser. Servlets work in a different way so I would not like to get into that. Try to focus on the the server implementation and get it sorted. I'm sure it will work correctly in iOS code. Cheers.